# Explicit expression for $\int_{0}^{+\infty} dr \,r e^{-\beta r^{2}}I_{0}(\beta r\rho)I_{0}(\beta r a)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I'm trying to calculate

$$\int_0^{+\infty}re^{-\beta r^2}I_0(\beta r\rho)I_0(\beta r a)\,dr,$$

where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of first kind and zero order.  This integral is equivalent (up to $2\pi$) to

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}re^{-\beta r(r+a\sin(\theta))}I_0(\beta r\rho) \, dr \, d\theta.$$

All constants here ($\beta$, $\rho$ and $a$) are positive. I see that this converges by plotting the function, but I cannot get any expressions (there's probably a trick I'm not seeing). Any suggestions are welcome

Note: the solution for $a=0$ can be found at
[The integral of exponential function and modified Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400277/the-integral-of-exponential-function-and-modified-bessel-function)

Comment: Notice this typographical difference:
$$
\begin{align}
& a sin\theta \\ {} \\
& a\sin\theta
\end{align}
$$
The latter is standard usage. The backslash has two effects that are visible here and one that is not: (1) $\sin$ is not italicized; (2) there is proper spacing between $a$ and $\sin,$ and (the one that is visible in other instances but not this one) (3) the following:
$$
\begin{align}
& a\sin(\theta) \\ {} \\
& a\sin\theta
\end{align}
$$
There is more space to the right of $\sin$ when no parenthesis is there. The spacing depends on the context. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy cool, thanks! haven't used latex notation in a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$F\left( a,b,c \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{x{{e}^{-c{{x}^{2}}}}{{I}_{0}}\left( ax \right){{I}_{0}}\left( bx \right)dx}$$
Then we have from the addition formula for Bessel functions
$${{I}_{0}}\left( w \right)=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty }{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{m}}{{I}_{m}}\left( Z \right){{I}_{m}}\left( z \right)\cos \left( m\phi  \right)}$$
where $w=\sqrt{{{Z}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}}-2Zz\cos \left( \phi  \right)}$.  From this, multiplying by $\cos \left( n\phi  \right)$for integer n, integrating over $\left[ 0,\pi  \right]$ and using the orthogonality of cosines, we find therefore
$$\frac{1}{\pi }\int\limits_{0}^{\pi }{{{I}_{0}}\left( w \right)d\phi }={{I}_{0}}\left( Z \right){{I}_{0}}\left( z \right)$$
So we have then
$$F\left( a,b,c \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{x{{e}^{-c{{x}^{2}}}}dx}\frac{1}{\pi }\int\limits_{0}^{\pi }{{{I}_{0}}\left( xw \right)d\phi }$$
where
$$w=\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}+{{b}^{2}}-2ab\cos \left( \phi  \right)}$$
Now consider using the series expansion for the Bessel function
$$\begin{align}
  & \int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{x{{e}^{-c{{x}^{2}}}}{{I}_{0}}\left( xw \right)dx}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{w}^{2k}}}{{{2}^{2k}}k{{!}^{2}}}}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{{{x}^{2k+1}}{{e}^{-c{{x}^{2}}}}dx}=\frac{1}{2c}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{w}^{2k}}\Gamma \left( k+1 \right)}{{{2}^{2k}}{{c}^{k}}k{{!}^{2}}}} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{2c}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }{{{\left( \frac{{{w}^{2}}}{4c} \right)}^{k}}\frac{1}{k!}=}\frac{1}{2c}{{e}^{\frac{{{w}^{2}}}{4c}}} \\ 
\end{align}$$
Then
$$F\left( a,b,c \right)=\frac{1}{\pi }\int\limits_{0}^{\pi }{\frac{1}{2c}{{e}^{\frac{{{w}^{2}}}{4c}}}d\phi }=\frac{1}{2c}{{e}^{\frac{{{a}^{2}}+{{b}^{2}}}{4c}}}\frac{1}{\pi }\int\limits_{0}^{\pi }{{{e}^{-\frac{ab}{2c}\cos \left( \phi  \right)}}d\phi }=\frac{1}{2c}{{e}^{\frac{{{a}^{2}}+{{b}^{2}}}{4c}}}{{I}_{0}}\left( \frac{ab}{2c} \right)$$
by the definition of the Bessel function.

Comment: yesss, thank you very much @mathstackuser12